# I cannot access to folders/files only in the desktop with click

Tags: mouse, directory, freeze, .desktop

I cannot access any folder or files in the desktop either by double-left click or with right click nor can I access wifi options but I do have access to icons on the desktop.

My Ubuntu version is 16.04.3 LTS.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried having a look to your permissions?
Try opening the terminal and typing `chmod 770 /home/*your username*/Desktop`
I hope it helps!

Comment: Yes I do! Is not a permission problem! when I click on a folder is like that I do anything . Desktop is only freeze but the other application on the left bar work fine!

Comment: Try a `sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: No problem mate! I'm glad it worked :)